# ant-design select not styled properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, antd

Using ant-design select to render a searchable select dropdown

From the documentation, I wrote the following component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Select } from 'antd';

const Option = Select.Option;

function handleChange(value) {
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
}

function handleBlur() {
  console.log('blur');
}

function handleFocus() {
  console.log('focus');
}

export default class SearchBarDemo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        showSearch
        style={{ width: 200 }}
        placeholder="Select a person"
        optionFilterProp="children"
        onChange={handleChange}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        filterOption={(input, option) => option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
      >
        <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
        <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
        <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
      </Select>
    );
  }
}
```

But the select drop-down is not stylized properly

Looks like below
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you imported css for ant.design?

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
```

My demo on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rvlqk36oq)